# distinguish whether page was reloaded or not in Django views or in template

Tags: django

Django question

I would like to ask whether it is  possible or not  to distinguish  in view or in template if page was reloaded or page was reached by url from the other page? If shorten it out, need to know if it is any marker that would indicate that page got reloaded by F5 or whatever?

Perhaps it is  probably possible to figure out by analyzing request.

Only 1 idea that comes to my mind is following:

```py
request.get_full_path()# – specifies full address of the current page

request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')# – specifies full address of previous page
```

So that theoretically if former == last – page is reloaded, but it doesn't work this way.

If you know any solution or hint -please communicate it.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect a browser refresh from a Django request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512608/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-browser-refresh-from-a-django-request)

Comment: @Bear Brown. I read that one. There are only JS solution on the issue

Comment: this text i mean `By itself, I believe there would not be a way to know a page was refreshed just by looking at a request object.`

Comment: [HTTP_REFERER and reload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1262371)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do one thing:

use one hidden element in your template like this :

```
 <input type="hidden" id="anyId" name="anyName" value="">
```

then call a fn to assign value to this element when page reloads

```
<body onbeforeunload="assignValue()>
<!--put your stuff-->
<script>
function assignValue(){
document.getElementById("anyId").value="reloaded";
}
</body>
```

because of `onbeforeunload` on page load `assignValue()` fn will be called.
then you can check this value of input element in your backend if value is not empty i.e. "" means page is loaded